# $content array not showing as expected

Tags: theming

This is a new install of Drupal 7.55, installed via drush.

I have installed the bootstrap theme and have created a subtheme that extends the bootstrap theme.

I have created a new Content Type called **Card** and within Card created a new field called **Grid Width (field_grid_width)**.

Within my subtheme I have created a new file node--card.tpl.php which is definitely being used.

When I try to access a field of Card using **$content['field_grid_width']** I get an index undefined error.

After seeking some advice it looks as though the $content array is in an unexpected format as I should be able to access the fields of a content type using the $content array.

Here is a print_r() of $content.

```
        Array
(
[links] => Array
    (
        [#theme] => links__node
        [#pre_render] => Array
            (
                [0] => drupal_pre_render_links
            )

        [#attributes] => Array
            (
                [class] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => links
                        [1] => inline
                    )

            )

        [node] => Array
            (
                [#theme] => links__node__node
                [#links] => Array
                    (
                        [node-readmore] => Array
                            (
                                [title] => Read more about Launching to Mars
                                [href] => node/1
                                [html] => 1
                                [attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [rel] => tag
                                        [title] => Launching to Mars
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [#attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [class] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => links
                                [1] => inline
                            )

                    )

            )

        [comment] => Array
            (
                [#theme] => links__node__comment
                [#links] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [#attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [class] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => links
                                [1] => inline
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[body] => Array
    (
        [#theme] => field
        [#weight] => 0
        [#title] => Body
        [#access] => 1
        [#label_display] => hidden
        [#view_mode] => teaser
        [#language] => und
        [#field_name] => body
        [#field_type] => text_with_summary
        [#field_translatable] => 0
        [#entity_type] => node
        [#bundle] => card
        [#object] => stdClass Object
            (
                [vid] => 1
                [uid] => 1
                [title] => Launching to Mars
                [log] => 
                [status] => 1
                [comment] => 1
                [promote] => 1
                [sticky] => 0
                [nid] => 1
                [type] => card
                [language] => und
                [created] => 1497537198
                [changed] => 1497538510
                [tnid] => 0
                [translate] => 0
                [revision_timestamp] => 1497538510
                [revision_uid] => 1
                [body] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras malesuada porta sem. Donec nec dolor sed leo 
tincidunt sodales. Ut quis ornare mauris, eget interdum urna. Sed egestas 
libero vel risus aliquam consectetur. Pellentesque mattis sed lorem in 
egestas. Nunc vel ornare lorem. Proin finibus tortor tortor, sit amet pharetra 
lacus elementum a. 
                                        [summary] => 
                                        [format] => filtered_html
                                        [safe_value] => 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras malesuada porta 
sem. Donec nec dolor sed leo tincidunt sodales. Ut quis ornare mauris, eget 
interdum urna. Sed egestas libero vel risus aliquam consectetur. Pellentesque 
mattis sed lorem in egestas. Nunc vel ornare lorem. Proin finibus tortor 
tortor, sit amet pharetra lacus elementum a.



                                        [safe_summary] => 
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [field_image] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [fid] => 1
                                        [uid] => 1
                                        [filename] => MARS_Helmets_DL.jpg
                                        [uri] => public://MARS_Helmets_DL.jpg
                                        [filemime] => image/jpeg
                                        [filesize] => 648162
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [timestamp] => 1497537198
                                        [rdf_mapping] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                        [alt] => 
                                        [title] => 
                                        [width] => 1920
                                        [height] => 1080
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [field_grid_width] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 5
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [rdf_mapping] => Array
                    (
                        [rdftype] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => sioc:Item
                                [1] => foaf:Document
                            )

                        [title] => Array
                            (
                                [predicates] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => dc:title
                                    )

                            )

                        [created] => Array
                            (
                                [predicates] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => dc:date
                                        [1] => dc:created
                                    )

                                [datatype] => xsd:dateTime
                                [callback] => date_iso8601
                            )

                        [changed] => Array
                            (
                                [predicates] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => dc:modified
                                    )

                                [datatype] => xsd:dateTime
                                [callback] => date_iso8601
                            )

                        [body] => Array
                            (
                                [predicates] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => content:encoded
                                    )

                            )

                        [uid] => Array
                            (
                                [predicates] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => sioc:has_creator
                                    )

                                [type] => rel
                            )

                        [name] => Array
                            (
                                [predicates] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => foaf:name
                                    )

                            )

                        [comment_count] => Array
                            (
                                [predicates] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => sioc:num_replies
                                    )

                                [datatype] => xsd:integer
                            )

                        [last_activity] => Array
                            (
                                [predicates] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => sioc:last_activity_date
                                    )

                                [datatype] => xsd:dateTime
                                [callback] => date_iso8601
                            )

                    )

                [cid] => 0
                [last_comment_timestamp] => 1497537198
                [last_comment_name] => 
                [last_comment_uid] => 1
                [comment_count] => 0
                [name] => Admin
                [picture] => 0
                [data] => b:0;
                [entity_view_prepared] => 1
            )

        [#items] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Cras malesuada porta sem. Donec nec dolor sed leo tincidunt 
sodales. Ut quis ornare mauris, eget interdum urna. Sed egestas libero vel 
risus aliquam consectetur. Pellentesque mattis sed lorem in egestas. Nunc vel 
ornare lorem. Proin finibus tortor tortor, sit amet pharetra lacus elementum 
a. 
                        [summary] => 
                        [format] => filtered_html
                        [safe_value] => 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras malesuada porta 
sem. Donec nec dolor sed leo tincidunt sodales. Ut quis ornare mauris, eget 
interdum urna. Sed egestas libero vel risus aliquam consectetur. Pellentesque 
mattis sed lorem in egestas. Nunc vel ornare lorem. Proin finibus tortor 
tortor, sit amet pharetra lacus elementum a.



                        [safe_summary] => 
                    )

            )

        [#formatter] => text_summary_or_trimmed
        [0] => Array
            (
                [#markup] => 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras malesuada porta 
sem. Donec nec dolor sed leo tincidunt sodales. Ut quis ornare mauris, eget 
interdum urna. Sed egestas libero vel risus aliquam consectetur. Pellentesque 
mattis sed lorem in egestas. Nunc vel ornare lorem. Proin finibus tortor 
tortor, sit amet pharetra lacus elementum a.


            )

    )

)
```

I know there is another way I can access the data using the $node array, however from my research on the Drupal website I should be able to access it using the $content?

Comment: In the display settings of the content type, is the field set to Display or is it hidden? If it is hidden, it won't be in the render array ($content).

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that solved the issue, could you add an answer so I can reward you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the display settings of the content type, the field should be set to Display. If it is hidden, it won't be in the render array ($content).